# Why is navigator.share only sharing text, not the URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigator

I have added a navigator.share function to my react app, but for some reason, it is only sharing the text from the object and not the URL? Is there something I am missing here?

```js
    function shareList() {
      if (navigator.canShare) {
        navigator.share({
          title: "Page Title",
          text: "brief description",
          url: window.location.href,
        });
      } else {
        //functionality for desktop
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Share..." onclick="shareList()"/>
```

On iOS, the share dialogue pops up properly, but the share object is just text and not a URL. Here is a screenshot of the pop-up

[Share dialogue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpVTW.jpg)

Comment: What site are you testing this on? If I run this in the console of any public HTTPS site, I do get the URL (Chrome browser on Windows combo). If you are trying this on localhost I'd expect that permissions may block it.

Comment: I updated the code snippet to (A) include the keyword 'function' before the function, and (B) tied it to an HTML element so that it can be tested. It does work for me here on StackOverflow in browsers (desktop too) that support it. e.g. Google Chrome. (note it will show the iframe'd URL from the snippet `https://stacksnippets.net/js`)

Comment: [`navigator.share`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) is available in secure contexts only, so if you're not on HTTPS, it may not be working.

Comment: Also note that [`navigator.canShare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/canShare) is a function, not a property, so that code just checks if the function exists, not if the data can be shared.

Comment: This code is running from my personal website which is on HTTPS. I tried the code snippet on my mobile device through stack overflow and I am still only getting the text (no URL), even on my mobile device. Possibly a setting on my iPhone if you are able to verify it works for you?

Edit: Yes can confirm it was just displaying weird on my mobile device. I am not sure what was happening but resetting my device fixed it

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue was with my device. I tested on another device soon after posting and it worked fine, and after restarting my device it worked as intended.